# PHP - Pattern em Datalist

Tags: php

Quero fazer um campo datalist em que o usuário possa digitar para encontrar o que deseja mais rápido, porém não quero que o usuário possa colocar algo fora dos valores sugeridos, por isso estou usando o pattern, porém o código não está funcionando e não consegui encontrar o motivo.

```
<?php 
        $select = "SELECT cod_categoria, desc_categoria
        FROM categoria
        ORDER BY cod_categoria";
        $result = $mysqli->query($select);

        echo "<input list='categoria' name='cat_prod' class='form-control' pattern='";                                                                                                                                              
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
              echo "".$row['desc_categoria']."|";                                                           
        }                                                   
        echo "' required>";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

        echo "<datalist id='categoria'>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<option value=".$row['desc_categoria']."/>";                                                          
        }   
        echo "</datalist>";
?>
```

Uma outra duvida é em relação ao segundo while, quero que repita a mesma quantidade de vezes que o primeiro, poderia colocar apenas while($row){  } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Datalist** ainda não é compatível com todos os browsers. Como você quer listar categorias pré-definidas, a melhor opção seria utilizar a tag **select**, ao invés de **input** com **datalist**. Seu código ficaria assim:

```
<?php 
    $select = "SELECT cod_categoria, desc_categoria
    FROM categoria
    ORDER BY cod_categoria";
    $result = $mysqli->query($select);

    echo "<select name='cat_prod' class='form-control'>";                                                                                                                                              
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          echo "<option value='" . $row['desc_categoria'] . "'>" 
               . $row['desc_categoria'] . "</option>";                                                           
    }                                                   
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Um motivo possível de não ter funcionado o seu código, foi a falta de delimitadores (' ') em **options**, fazendo com que categorias com espaços possam trazer problemas. O segundo problema tem a ver com a sua segunda pergunta, já que você está tentando utilizar o resultado da sua query duas vezes. Existem inúmeras soluções, mas vou guardar em um array chamado **$categorias** e depois apresento os valores utilizando o [implode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) e o [foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
<?php 
    $select = "SELECT cod_categoria, desc_categoria
    FROM categoria
    ORDER BY cod_categoria";
    $result = $mysqli->query($select);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          $categorias[] = $row['desc_categoria'];                                                                                                             
    }

    echo "<input list='categoria' name='cat_prod' class='form-control' pattern='" 
         . implode('|', $categorias) . "' required>";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

    echo "<datalist id='categoria'>";
    foreach($categorias as $categoria){
        echo "<option value='".$categoria."'/>";                                                          
    }   
    echo "</datalist>";
?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu já tinha feito com o select que sabia que funcionava, como no seu primeiro exemplo. Porém eu testei o segundo exemplo utilizando foreach e implode e deu certo. O problema era justamente a falta de "" '' separadores.